# Can parameters have same name as a global variable and still called inside a function?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int x = 12;

void foo(int x)
{
  printf("%d\n",x);
}

int main() 
{
  foo(3);
  printf("%d\n",x);
  return 0;
}
```

This gives output

```
3
12
```

How can i access global int x inside the function foo()?

Comment: Local variable/parameter shadows the global variable. Just use a different name.  `x` is not the most explanatory name for a global, and 99% of the time you don't want to use a global at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but the parameter shadows it. Just use another name for parameter variable in `foo` function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works like this as variables of same names are allowed provided that they are in different scopes. "x" is both defined in global scope (global variable) and a local scope (in foo() as a parameter). But they are located in different locations in memory.